# How to get the line number in an Activity in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can i get the line number in the left hand side of the Activty in eclipse. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before it used to be:
Window → Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors → Show line numbers.

but now we can simply do :
1.Right Click in the Gutter(left side of your activity: As shown in figure)
2. And then Click "Show Line Numbers".

[image]

Another way is using shortcuts like : Ctrl+F10, then press n "it show line number and hide line numbers.

You can try these steps that works best for you. 
Thanks.

Comment: great.. it works..The second option is the easiest one